# How to alter bLengthChange property through a function callback in DataTable?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a table, and using DataTable plugin, I wan't to hide the `show-x-rows` drop-down menu, when there are less than 10 search results.

I am doing something like this:

```
$('.datatable').DataTable({

                      :
                      :

      "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings){

         var rowCount = this.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay();

         if(rowCount<=10){

         $('.datatable.dataTables_length').css("display":"none");
           //something like this.

         or,  

         $('.datatable').bLengthChange.value(false);
         //something like this.            

         }
      }
});
```

I have tried putting an `alert(rowCount)` after the if statement, and it is getting triggered normally, which means the required value is getting stored in rowCount variable and the code is working the way it should be untill the `$('.datatable')..` statement.

So, at this point inside this function, I want to change the value of `bLengthChange` property to false. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I resolved this by doing the following:

```
  "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings){

     var rowCount = this.fnSettings().fnRecordsDisplay();

     if(rowCount<=10){

      $('.dataTables_length').hide();           

     }
  }
```